# Powershell GUI properties

Tags: powershell

I would like to create form and other controls (`TextBox`, `ComboBox`, `ListBox` etc) in `powershell`. I don't want to use any 3rd Party tool for creating them. 
I did the finding but i didn't found any document or website that have property details  of these elements.

Could you please advise me where i can get the property name/details of form and other element.

eg.

```
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size

$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 257

$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 352

$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$form1.Name = "form1"

$form1.Text = "Form"
```

Thanks

Comment: take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The link you given here have details only about System Drawing. How can i get the element name for form, label, textbox etc?

Comment: use the search box on top of the msdn page ...

Comment: I did the search but not getting the correct link. There are multiple links. Is there any other website available?

Comment: this is the first  result for textbox http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx do you want us to search in your place ???

Comment: No. Thats enough. thanks for your help.